# What time does NT time start on

Tags: windows, date-time

Unix time starts on January 1st, 1970. What time does WinNT time start?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the standard unix time apis, Windows can return time starting from 1601:

[SYSTEMTIME structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)